# Stop MediaPlayer at certain point

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Hi guys Im trying to stop mediaplayer in certain point but it doesnt work for me below is my code let me know what is wrong in this code.

```
int Str = 36000;
                int Stop = 51000;
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(Str);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() == Stop)
                {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
```

Media player starts at the specified point and it continues to play, when I debug it, it comes to the if condition and it still continues to play no error(as far I know) is displayed, I played with while, if condition and debug line by line but cant figure out,Please help me Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to bound the time:

```
while(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() >= Str && mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= Stop)
{
}
```

However, use this wisely, you might freeze something and end up in ANR.

You mind find useful using `Thread` or `Handler` delaying for 1000ms, but as @dhaag23 mentioned, its unlikely to get exact `Stop`

Comment: Thx for the suggestion Bounding freeze other buttons in my app and still it doesnt stop the mp3.

Comment: thx yes as you said I don't have exact change but i used Handler and thread to read the mp3 current position and used bounds as u suggested and it worked, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Media player commands typically execute asynchronously so the chances of you're getting the current position to be exactly the "stop" position is unlikely. Maybe you want to change your test to:

```
if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() >= Stop)
```

Comment: :Thx for the reply, but in my case it never stops it ignores the if condition and plays to the end , Stop is not invoked

Comment: I think it ignores the if condition for some reason, I tries the above but again it plays the whole file not stop at all